# Unable to Deploy Databricks Notebook with provided Databricks Extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks

I am using Azure Devops to deploy Databricks Notebooks. I have installed two extensions, as shown in the image.

[image]

The first extension ' Databricks Deploy Notebooks' successfully deploys a notebook to Databricks. However, the second extension 'Execute Databricks Notebook' fail's with the error:

> Unable to locate executable file: 'databricks'. Please verify either
>   the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory
>   specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a
>   valid extension for an executable file.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried adding the "Configure Databricks CLI" task before "Execute"?

Comment: @Daniel, I just about to submit my own answer to say exactly you suggested fixed the issue. Yes, adding  "Configure Databricks CLI" task before "Execute" executed the task successfully. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was suggested by Daniel, I needed to add the extension  "Configure Databricks CLI" task before "Execute". After adding the extension before "Execute" the task completed successfully.